# UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be incompatible with each other: <empty list>

Tags: python, conda

While trying to install a custom package from a self-hosted repository, we get a weird error.

```
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Solving environment: failed with repodata from current_repodata.json, will retry with next repodata source.
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Solving environment: |
Found conflicts! Looking for incompatible packages.
This can take several minutes.  Press CTRL-C to abort.
failed


UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be incompatible with each other:


Output in format: Requested package -> Available versions
```

... and that's it. One would expect a list of actual conflicts, but there is none.

We have checked the dependencies of the package in question manually, but they are all fulfilled.

We have installed another self-made package from this repository successfully. What can we do to get a sensible error message, to diagnose or to solve the problem?

Edit: When I first encountered this problem, the answer I gave below solved the problem. Now I'm having the problem again (same custom repository, different package) and the answer does not help.

Answer (score 0):

What solved the issue was to re-order the channels into this order:

- defaults
- conda-forge
- *custom channel*